# How to use a char string as a mathematical operator?

Tags: c++

I'm working on a class assignment and I'm trying to use a char as an operator, but the IDE keeps telling me it is expecting a semicolon at op in (return operand1 ***op*** operand2;).  What am I missing here?

Operand1 and operand2 are both floats, and char op is limited to being +, -, *, or /.

```
float evaluatePrefix::evaluatePre(string strExp)
{
    strLength = strExp.length();
    if (strLength == 1)
        return strExp[0];
    else
    {
        char op = strExp[0];

        int endFirst = endPre(strExp, 1);

        float operand1 = evaluatePre(strExp.substr[1, endFirst]);

        int endSecond = strLength - endFirst + 1;
        float operand2 = evaluatePre(strExp.substr[endFirst + 1,   endSecond]);

        //float theAnswer = operand1 op operand2;

        return operand1 op operand2;
    }
}
```

Comment: `strExp.substr[1, endFirst]` isn't valid C++. Perhaps you mean `strExp.substr(1, endFirst)`?

Comment: "What am I missing here?" , you can't sub in a mathematical operator at runtime.

Comment: this is called wishful thinking programming

Comment: @scohe001 Thank you for catching that.  But it doesn't solve the issue.  Additionally, if I state 'return operand1 + operand2;' no warning is thrown.  Yet if I add an 'if op = "+" return operand1 + operand2;' it says it is looking for )

Comment: You can't use a `char` variable as an operator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't simply do

```
char plus = '+';
int result = 2 plus 2;
```

That's just not how C++ works... But you can use a switch or if statement.

ie.

```
if (op == '+') {
    return operand1 + operand2;
} else if (op == '-') {
    return operand1 - operand2;
} ...
```

Comment: Ohhhh.  Thank you very much @ACVM  That makes sense.